# Why can't I get my dropdown menu to work in my bootstrap nav?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site here http://defend-foreclosure.com using the latest version of bootstrap. For some reason, my dropdown for "Law" in the navbar is not working. I've included all JS files and for some reason it just won't work no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap.min.js is missing from your website just copy bootstrap.min.js to js directory on your website and add this in all html pages.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I tested and it worked!

Comment: So I uploaded a jquery.js file from here http://jquery.com/.

The dropdown still is not working properly. Can anyone see what else I might be missing?

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You are missing an other java script file from the bootstrap package called bootstrap.min.js, i edited the answer!